# PayPal IPN returning INVALID even after payment is sent

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am developing a shopping cart application, and in that application, I decided to integrate PayPal IPN. However, it keeps returning INVALID. It successfully transfers money and is deducted from my account and moved to the buyer's account.

```
if ( ! count($_POST)) {
    throw new \Exception("Missing POST Data");
}
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = [];
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2) {
        // Since we do not want the plus in the datetime string to be encoded to a space, we manually encode it.
        if ($keyval[0] === 'payment_date') {
            if (substr_count($keyval[1], '+') === 1) {
                $keyval[1] = str_replace('+', '%2B', $keyval[1]);
            }
        }
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
    }
}
// Build the body of the verification post request, adding the _notify-validate command.
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
$get_magic_quotes_exists = false;
if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if ($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// Post the data back to PayPal, using curl. Throw exceptions if errors occur.
$ch = curl_init(self::VERIFY_URI);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
// This is often required if the server is missing a global cert bundle, or is using an outdated one.

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, __DIR__ . "/cert/cacert.pem");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Connection: Close']);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$http_code = $info['http_code'];
if ($http_code != 200) {
    throw new \Exception("PayPal responded with http code $http_code");
}
if ( ! ($res)) {
    $errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $errstr = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    throw new \Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
}
curl_close($ch);
// Check if PayPal verifies the IPN data, and if so, return true.
if ($res == "VERIFIED") {
    return 'success';
} else {
    return print_r($res, true);
    }
```

My inputs and outputs are exactly the same. However, this particular key is different:

INPUT: `[payment_date] => 2016-12-09T15:07:18Z`
OUTPUT: `payment_date=2016-12-09T14%3A12%3A21Z` (After the query is made).

Comment: You need to look at the data being sent in your IPN history and the POST data being sent to Paypal. Then you will be able to figure what is wrong or share it here.

Comment: I did observe. I can share it here. One second.

Comment: @DavidNguyen Check now. Updated.

Comment: That looks fine but why did the payment date change?

Comment: @DavidNguyen Due to the encoding/decoding process in this script. I think that is what is making it INVALID? How would I fix this issue?

Comment: I would take out the entire part starting with ` if (count($keyval) == 2) {` not sure why it is there

Comment: @DavidNguyen Apparently, it is needed to encode and stuff.

Comment: Doesn't make sense because the data is posted, you shouldn't have to decode it before encoding it.  I would get the latest IPN example from PHP. I do not have any lines that urldecode data in my IPN.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same error yesterday. Try the following:

```
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

   if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
         return "Success";
    }else if (strcmp($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
       //deal with invalid IPN
       //mail admin or alert client
}
```

PayPal IPN variables are already encoded and there is no need to do it twice, replace with this code below

```
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc()){  
    $varvalue = urlencode(stripslashes($varvalue)); 
}
else { 
    $value = urlencode($value); 
}
```

Comment: it keeps saying INVALID.

Comment: Can you give me your full source?

Comment: did you use the class i referred you to?

Comment: Ok I got that. Do you have to use the code above in that?

Comment: You want me to remove that part?